# Behavior in Logial OR

Tags: javascript

I am experiencing this:

```
true || "Word"
true

false || "Word"
'Word'

undefined || "Word"
'Word'
```

I assume it is correct, but I don't understand the logic behind it.

Comment: [_” the `||` operator actually returns the value of one of the specified operands”_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR)

Comment: of course...... And it is clear that if one is undefined, it returns the other one. But why the second, I expected it returned "false"

Comment: for logical And operation it would return false but this is OR operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is pretty simple. For OR operation it returns the first truthy value or false if all conditions are false.

Example:

```
true || "Word"
```

Here from left to right if you read the first condtion is true. hence it won't execute the rest of the part and return true.

```
false || "Word"
```

here the first condition is false, hence it will continue checking the next condition which is a string. Any string is considered a truthy value hence it returns the string "Word"

```
undefined || "Word"
```

In javascript undefined is considered a falsy. Hence, It returns the next part which is true as it is a string.

now lets check a more complex condition:

```
false || undefined || "Word" || true
```

In this exmaple, first condition is false, second is falsy since undefined is considered falsy, third one is true as it is a string. Hence it will return that without going to check the next condition. So final result is "Word"